# Mutants & Masterminds 3rd Edition Spreadsheet

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, tool-recommendation, mutants-and-masterminds

Build Point systems tend to be math heavy, and that makes it especially difficult when playing with kids.  Even with advanced degrees, I prefer to let computers to my math for me.  Over the years I've used several spreadsheets for several systems, such as the Shadowrun Character Generator Spreadsheet at the bottom of [Aaron's Shadowrun Resources Site](http://pavao.org/shadowrun/generators/).  It not only keeps me honest, but it means I don't make silly arithmetic mistakes.

Does anyone know of such a beast for M&M 3.0?

Note: I've found Hero Lab, and I would shell out the money it *but* I run Linux and the demo I downloaded from their site has a tendency to crash under wine.  I don't know if it does the same under Windows, or if the licensed version similarly crashes, but I hate spending money on software that crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guy calling himself Ski over on the Atomic Think Tank forums put together a spreadsheet for *DC Adventures*, which runs on the same ruleset.

You can find it in [his thread for the thing](https://web.archive.org/web/20140807055158/http://atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=37151).  It seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Color me clueless.  I KNEW DC Adventures was the same game (heck, I own both), but didn't search for it.  I'm going to check this out tonight, and if it's as good as it looks as first glance I'll send you the accept!  Thanks!

Comment: So ... it's a tad clunky when it gets to powers, but it definitely works as advertised!  Thanks again!

Comment: @goofdad A little bit, but most of that is to enable arrays in something like a sane fashion.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

since Atomic Think Tank is gone you can find them here

Version 1.28 (Excel 97-2003 Compatible)
http://www.box.net/shared/b4m59seun0

Version 1.28 (Excel 2007)
http://www.box.net/shared/fmm1s56ip7